# Typescript Vue class-based components throwing error Cannot set property 'render' of undefined in Laravel mix

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel Mix to compile my Vue components and for it, I used TypeScript and class-based components. Every single class is exported from the component, and every single component is required by the context in the main application script but during rendering Vue throwing error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'render' of undefined
    at normalizeComponent (componentNormalizer.js:24)
```

I searched all of the Internet but people speak only about invalid export class. I'm sure about valid exporting class in components. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

When I back to object-based components in plain JavaScript everything goes perfect, so maybe TypeScript config is wrong or something. I give up completely :(

**app.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import _ from "lodash"

export default class App {

    protected registerComponents(): void {
        const components = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);

        components.keys().forEach((componentPath) => {
            // @ts-ignore
            const componentName = componentPath
                .split('/').pop() // full component name
                .split('.').slice(0, 1).shift(); // component name without extension

            Vue.component(
                _.kebabCase(componentName),
                components(componentPath)
            );
        })
    }

    protected boot(): void {
        this.registerComponents();
    }

    public init(): Vue {
        this.boot();

        return new Vue({
            el: '#main',
        });
    }
}
```

**EventSignUpForm.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Long-form v-model example</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import {Component} from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component({
        name: 'EventSignUpForm',
    })
    export class EventSignUpForm extends Vue {

        protected count = 0

        public increment() {
            this.count++
        }

        public decrement() {
            this.count--
        }
    }

    export default EventSignUpForm;
</script>
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "types": [
            "node",
            "webpack-env"
        ],
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./resources/js/*"]
        },
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "scripthost"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "resources/js/**/*.ts",
        "resources/js/**/*.tsx",
        "resources/js/**/*.vue"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
class WebpackMix {
    constructor() {
        this.mix = require('laravel-mix');
    }

    configureWebpack(){
        this.mix.webpackConfig({
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.tsx?$/,
                        loader: "ts-loader",
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                    }
                ]
            },
            resolve: {
                extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".vue", ".ts", ".tsx"],
                alias: {
                    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', 'js'),
                },
            }
        });
    }
    // others things  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workmate helps me solve this quite a difficult case.

What we do is add in **webpack.mix.js** to *ts-loader* options object. We need append TS suffix to Vue components. Now it is:

```js
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    options: {
      appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
    }
  }
]
```

What we do next is change **tsconfig.js** *compilerOptions.module* to be **commonjs** instead of **es2015**, like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        // the rest remain unchanged
    }
}
```

As last thing all of imports/require Vue components must be the default import, I used just import in *require.context* but it must be changed to such:

```
protected registerComponents(): void {
  const components = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);

  components.keys().forEach((componentPath) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    const componentName = componentPath
      .split('/').pop() // full component name
      .split('.').slice(0, 1).shift(); // component name without extension

    Vue.component(
      _.kebabCase(componentName),
      components(componentPath).default
    );
  })
}
```

This solves my problem, thanks to Adrian for your time and give working solution :)

Answer (score 2):

**EventSignUpForm.vue**:
Make component `export` as `export default`:

```
export class EventSignUpForm extends Vue
```

change to be

```
export default class EventSignUpForm extends Vue
```

and remove from bottom

```
export default EventSignUpForm;
```